# New Excel VBA compile error upon saving workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using the code below to successfully create and save a new workbook for each worksheet in my workbook.  When I try to run it now I get an error "Compile Error Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments".  I cannot see why it is not working now; it did before.  I do want the date in the final name.  If I run the code with the wb.SaveAs line marked with ' it works fine.  It doesn't seem to like the format part now.  Any ideas what is different and why? Thank-you.

```
Sub Make_Workbooks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
'wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
ws.Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Next ws

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax used to use the `SaveAs` should be ***FileName***, ***FileFormat***, ....

In your code it should be:

```
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

(`xlOpenXMLWorkbook` = ".xlsx")

If you will run your code a few times every day, you will get a message if you want to overwrite the existing file since `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")` will have the same `String` on the same day.

If you want to automatically overwrite your previous file, then add the line `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Make_Workbooks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ' add this line to automatically overwrite the exisitng file (not getting the MsgBox on every time)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ws.Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next ws

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Edit1**: If you want to make sure 2 file names never have the same name, you can use the `Now` function:

```
wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh_mm_ss"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses and ideas.  I made edits to my code but still get a compile error when I add to the wb.SaveAs line the Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") part.  When I remove the date it saves the file fine.

Comment: @Andes2016 did you copy my entire code and still got the error ? see my **Edit1** note, maybe you can use it

Comment: Yes I did copy the code and still get the error.  By the way what is the purpose of Option Explicit?  That line, when I copy the code, is not included in the macro (i.e. Option Explicit is separated from the Sub code line by a line).

Comment: @Andes2016 did you try replacing the `SaveAs` line with my proposed solution in **Edit1** ? `Option Explicit` see MSDN link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx

Comment: Yes I did and I still get the compile error.  The Sub line is highlighted in yellow and the word Format is highlighted in blue.

Comment: is this code all you have in your `Sub` ? do you have other code ?

Comment: @Andes2016 I'm almost out of ideas why it works for me, and errors for you. Last try, what are your worksheet name ?

Comment: Thanks for providing input Shai.  I gave up in the end and decided to rebuild the file and re-use the code.  After I rebuilt the file the code worked as intended; still puzzled why I had the issue I did.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem on my system, but the following code minimizes the explicit creation and tracking of new Workbook objects, so it may be less error-prone across different environments:

```
Sub Make_Workbooks()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Copy     'Copies current sheet to new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWindow.Close
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for the idea and I see how you streamlined the code.  I found though that I need the three blank worksheets the original code had as I use those later.  I suppose I could use the insert worksheets function with your code?